# Strange behavior of `url_for` with argument `params`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby 2.1.1 and Ruby on Rails 4.1.1.

Given...

... I access the URL

```
http://www.example.org/users/1/ciao/edit?hash[controller]=articles&hash[action]=index
```

... in the rendered edit view, within the form, I have:

```
<% hash[:hash].each do |key, value| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag("hash[#{key}]", value) %>
<% end %>
```

... in my controller I have:

```
logger.debug "params        => #{params.inspect}" 
logger.debug "params[:hash] => #{params[:hash].inspect}" 

url_for(params[:hash].merge(:only_path => true))
```

When I submit the form then, by logging, I get:

```
params        => { "hash" => { "controller" => "articles", "action" => "index" }, "user_id" => "1", "controller" => "users/ciao", "action" => "update", "users_ciao" => { "language"=>"it" }, "_method" => "patch", "commit" => "Update", "utf8" => "✓"}
params[:hash] => { "controller" => "articles", "action" => "index" }

ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches { :controller => "users/articles", :action => "show", :user_id => "1"}):
```

*In* `url_for` I passed `params[:hash]` that should be `{ "controller" => "articles", "action" => "show" }`, right? Why I get `:controller => "users/articles"` and the added `:user_id => "1"`?! Is it a bug?

The strange behavior relates an automatic namespacing: when I inspect `params[:hash]` it is `{ "controller" => "articles", "action" => "index" }` but when I pass it to the `url_for` method it becomes `{ :controller => "users/articles", :action => "show", :user_id => "1"}`.

---

Note: The problem does not occur with *not* nested resources. That is, for instance, when the initial URL is as-like

```
http://www.example.org/users/1/edit?hash[controller]=articles&hash[action]=index
```

---

By looking at the [`ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor#url_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L150) source code I see it runs `reverse_merge!(url_options)` when `options` is a `Hash`.

After some deeping I came up by using the following code (that seems to work as expected) in order to skip the `reverse_merge!(url_options)`:

```
_routes.url_for(params[:hash].merge(:only_path => true).symbolize_keys)
```

instead of using:

```
url_for(params[:hash].merge(:only_path => true))
```

It happens even by using Ruby on Rails 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` automatically prompts namespace for controller unless it is an absolute one, so if you don't need `user` namespace then you could write:

`controller: '/articles'`

Comment: I know that, but the problem is related to "the strange behavior" (maybe an automatic namespacing): when I inspect `params[:hash]` it is `{ "controller" => "articles", "action" => "index" }` but when I pass it to the `url_for` method it becomes `{ :controller => "users/articles", :action => "show", :user_id => "1"}`. Refer to the error message in the question.

Comment: your controller `articles` is automatically changed to `users/articles` and `user_id` is added from `@user` variable, if you write `/articles` then `user_id` also should disappear